# How to analyse flurry event parameters?

Tags: objective-c, flurry

I am tracking events of my game with flurry analytics. So far I like it a lot, but I have a question concerning the parameters of the events.

Right now I have a generic level_win event that has parameters like score, time, levelnumber and so on. What I want to do is create a statistic on how long it took the players to finish a certain level. Is there a possibility to get that information with flurry? Right now the web interface only shows pie charts for all parameters, but that is not what I need. I want to select a parameter (levelnumber) and see the other parameters of the events, but only of those that have the levelnumber parameter set to the value I want to inspect.

Any insights on how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use timed event for this. In the flurry API there is method called it when someone enters at particular level

```
 NSDictionary *flurryParam = @{@"param": @"Send some data"};
[Flurry logEvent:@"Time_Taken" withParameters:flurryParam timed:YES];
```

And when level is finished

```
 NSDictionary *flurryParam = @{@"param": @"Send some data"};
[Flurry endTimedEvent:@"Time_Taken" withParameters:flurryParam];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the simple solution of just creating a unique event for each level, basically just appending the level number to the level_win event. This will clutter up your events list, but I'm fairly certain it's the only way to get what you want.